# Truncate TinyMCE content in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, tinymce, truncate

Before I used `<% = truncate (@article.content,: length => 100)%>` to truncate the content and it worked.

Now I use TinyMCE I tried `<% = truncate (@article.content.html_safe,: length => 100)%>` but the contents are not truncated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution `<%= truncate(strip_tags(@article.content.html_safe),: length => 100)%>`